# Show that there exist $\{x_n\}$ a sequence of elements in $A- \{x\}$ such that $x_n \to x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis, normed-spaces

Let $E$ a normed vector space and $A \subset E$. Let $x$ an accumulation point in $A$. Show that there exist $\{x_n\}$ a sequence of elements in $A- \{x\}$ such that $x_n \to x$.

**Definition :**
An accumulation point $x$ is a point such that $B(x,r) \cap A - \{x\} \not= \emptyset$

I tried to prove by contradiction, but I am a bit blocked. Is anyone could give me a good hint to solve the problem?

Comment: Could you provide your definition of an accumulation point? (For metric spaces this is one possible definition, but probably not in your case.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Since $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$ for each $n$ in there exist an $x_n\in A-\{x\}$ such that $||x-x_n||<\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U_n=\{y\in E: \|y-x\|<1/n\}$, for $n\ge1$ integer. Then $U_n$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and, by definition of accumulation point, there is $x_n\in U_n\cap A$, $x_n\ne x$.

Prove that the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$.